# Shouldn't be a button to the mobile address of the current page?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, mobile-web

I usually read/answer stadkoverflow Desktop version from a mobile device but sometimes code does not show very well so I want to change to mobile version but there is no such a link. Wouldn't be useful to have such a link somewhere in current page?

EDIT: I thought http://stackmobile.com/ was made by stackoverflow guys ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mobile version, however, there are a bunch of mobile apps for browsing Stack Overflow at http://stackapps.com